# Sassify the code

Tags: css, sass

I have few lines of code in scss file, I am new to sass/scss. How can I make this following Css into scss (make use of sass features)?

```
#l-header, #l-hnav, #l-footer {
   width: 728px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
#l-content {
   padding: 10px 10px 30px 12px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 704px;
}
#col12_2 {
   width: 704px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
}
 .mlid-dl_v2{
   height: 400px;
}
#col1 {
   clear: both;
   float: left;
   padding-top: 3px;
   width: 326px;
}
#col2 {
   padding-left: 22px;
   padding-top: 3px;
   width: 233px;
}
#col3 {
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 400px;
   right: 20px;
   width: 301px;
}
```

Comment: This is already valid scss code.

Comment: What features of SASS in particular are you trying to use?

Comment: It is valid sass/scss. Just want to learn how to better use of scss feature.

Comment: If you want to learn, go read some tutorials.  "Write my code for me, plz" type questions are frowned on around here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I recommend checking out http://sass-lang.com/guide for some of the stuff that can be done with sass and seeing which features suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You used the tag [sass](/questions/tagged/sass), which is described as

> Sass (Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets) is an extension of CSS adding
>   features like nested rules, variables and mixins. This extends the
>   possibility to write structured, manageable and reusable CSS. Sass
>   translates to standard CSS.

That means:

1. Valid CSS is already valid SCSS, you don't need to do anything to switch from CSS to SASS.
2. After switching to SASS, you can use SASS features.
3. Remember at the end you must compile SASS to CSS.